# Filter through XML data with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, filter

I am trying to filter through my XML using XSLT. I have a list of programming standards, and I am trying to figure out how to display all the languages that have that specific standard in a table data cell. So far, I have got it displaying all languages in each cell. My logic is off. Ideas?

XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="standards_XSL.xsl"?>

<programming>
  <languages>
    <language id="1">
      <name>C</name>
      <purpose>
        <intendedUse id="1" />
        <intendedUse id="2" />
        <intendedUse id="3" />
        <intendedUse id="4" />
      </purpose>
      <features>
        <feature id="1" />
        <feature id="4" />
      </features>
      <standards>
        <standard id="1" />
        <standard id="2" />
      </standards>
    </language>
    <language id="2">
      <name>C++</name>
      <purpose>
        <intendedUse id="1" />
        <intendedUse id="2" />
      </purpose>
      <features>
        <feature id="1" />
        <feature id="2" />
        <feature id="3" />
        <feature id="4" />
        <feature id="5" />
      </features>
      <standards>
        <standard id="2" />
      </standards>
    </language>
    <language id="3">
      <name>C#</name>
      <purpose>
        <intendedUse id="1" />
        <intendedUse id="5" />
        <intendedUse id="6" />
        <intendedUse id="7" />
        <intendedUse id="3" />
        <intendedUse id="8" />
        <intendedUse id="9" />
      </purpose>
      <features>
        <feature id="1" />
        <feature id="2" />
        <feature id="3" />
        <feature id="4" />
        <feature id="5" />
        <feature id="6" />
        <feature id="7" />
      </features>
      <standards>
        <standard id="3" />
        <standard id="2" />
      </standards>
    </language>
    <language id="4">
      <name>Java</name>
      <purpose>
        <intendedUse id="1" />
        <intendedUse id="6" />
        <intendedUse id="7" />
        <intendedUse id="3" />
        <intendedUse id="8" />
        <intendedUse id="9" />
      </purpose>
      <features>
        <feature id="1" />
        <feature id="2" />
        <feature id="5" />
        <feature id="6" />
      </features>
      <standards>
        <standard id="4" />
      </standards>
    </language>
    <language id="5">
      <name>JavaScript</name>
      <purpose>
        <intendedUse id="7" />
        <intendedUse id="8" />
        <intendedUse id="7" />
      </purpose>
      <features>
        <feature id="1" />
        <feature id="2" />
        <feature id="3" />
        <feature id="6" />
      </features>
      <standards>
        <standard id="3" />
      </standards>
    </language>
    <language id="6">
      <name>PHP</name>
      <purpose>
        <intendedUse id="8" />
        <intendedUse id="9" />
      </purpose>
      <features>
        <feature id="1" />
        <feature id="2" />
        <feature id="4" />
        <feature id="6" />
      </features>
      <standards>
        <standard id="5" />
      </standards>
    </language>
    <language id="7">
      <name>Python</name>
      <purpose>
        <intendedUse id="1" />
        <intendedUse id="3" />
        <intendedUse id="9" />
        <intendedUse id="10" />
        <intendedUse id="11" />
        <intendedUse id="12" />
      </purpose>
      <features>
        <feature id="1" />
        <feature id="2" />
        <feature id="3" />
        <feature id="6" />
      </features>
      <standards>
        <standard id="5" />
      </standards>
    </language>
    <language id="8">
      <name>Basic</name>
      <purpose>
        <intendedUse id="1" />
        <intendedUse id="13" />
      </purpose>
      <features>
        <feature id="1" />
        <feature id="4" />
      </features>
      <standards>
        <standard id="1" />
        <standard id="2" />
      </standards>
    </language>
    <language id="9">
      <name>ADA</name>
      <purpose>
        <intendedUse id="1" />
        <intendedUse id="2" />
        <intendedUse id="14" />
        <intendedUse id="15" />
      </purpose>
      <features>
        <feature id="1" />
        <feature id="2" />
        <feature id="4" />
        <feature id="5" />
      </features>
      <standards>
        <standard id="1" />
        <standard id="2" />
        <standard id="6" />
      </standards>
    </language>
    <language id="10">
      <name>ActionScript 3.0</name>
      <purpose>
        <intendedUse id="1" />
        <intendedUse id="7" />
        <intendedUse id="9" />
      </purpose>
      <features>
        <feature id="1" />
        <feature id="2" />
        <feature id="7" />
      </features>
      <standards>
        <standard id="3" />
      </standards>
    </language>
  </languages>

  <purpose>
    <intendedUse id="1"> Application</intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="2"> System </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="3"> General Purpose </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="4"> Low-Level Operations </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="5"> RAD </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="6"> Business </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="7"> Client-Side </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="8"> Server-Side </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="9"> Web </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="10"> Scripting </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="11"> AI </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="12"> Scientific Computing </intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="13">Education</intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="14">Embedded</intendedUse>
    <intendedUse id="15">RealTime</intendedUse>
  </purpose>
  <features>
    <feature id="1">Imperative </feature>
    <feature id="2">Object-Oriented</feature>
    <feature id="3">Functional</feature>
    <feature id="4">Procedural</feature>
    <feature id="5">Generic</feature>
    <feature id="6">Reflective</feature>
    <feature id="7">Event-Driven</feature>
  </features>
  <standards>
    <standard id="1">ANSI</standard>
    <standard id="2">ISO</standard>
    <standard id="3">ECMA</standard>
    <standard id="4">DE FACTO</standard>
    <standard id="5">NO</standard>
    <standard id="6">GOST</standard>
  </standards>
</programming>
```

UPDATE XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="language-by-standard" match="language" use="standards/standard/@id" />
   <xsl:param name="selectedStandard">ECMA</xsl:param>


<xsl:template match="/" >
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Standards</th>
                    <th>Language</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="programming/standards[standard=$selectedStandard]">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$selectedStandard"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:for-each select="key('language-by-standard', /programming/standards/standard/@id)" >
                                <xsl:value-of select="name" />
                                <br />
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: **1**. Please cut short your input to what is enough to describe the problem. **2**. Please post the expected output for that input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML uses IDs to link languages to standards. XSLT has a built-in [**key**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key) mechanism to handle inner links and perform a lookup.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="language-by-standard" match="language" use="standards/standard/@id" />

<xsl:template match="/" >
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Standards</th>
                    <th>Language</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="programming/standards/standard">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:for-each select="key('language-by-standard', @id)" >
                                <xsl:value-of select="name" />
                                <br />
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result (rendered)**:

[image]

Or, if you prefer:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="language-by-standard" match="language" use="standards/standard/@id" />

<xsl:template match="/" >
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Standards</th>
                    <th>Language</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="programming/standards/standard">
                    <xsl:variable name="languages" select="key('language-by-standard', @id)" />
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="{count($languages)}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$languages[1]/name" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$languages[position() > 1]" >
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="name" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to produce:

[image]

which may be more useful if you plan to expand the table further to the right.

---

### Edit:

In response to your update: if you only want to see the languages for the selected standard passed as a parameter, then there will be only one row in the Standards column - so that:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="selectedStandard">ECMA</xsl:param>
<xsl:key name="language-by-standard" match="language" use="standards/standard/@id" />

<xsl:template match="/" >
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Standard</th>
                    <th>Languages</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$selectedStandard"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:for-each select="key('language-by-standard', programming/standards/standard[.=$selectedStandard]/@id)" >
                            <xsl:value-of select="name" />
                            <br />
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <th>Standard</th>
            <th>Languages</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>ECMA</td>
            <td>C#<br>JavaScript<br>ActionScript 3.0<br></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Now, i want to try and filter with parameters. how can i implement this? I am using parameters.

@michael.hor257k 

I have the selected standard showing, but when it comes to filtering the langauges, it doesnt display anything unless i manually input the id.

I will add what i have so far and my output.

Comment: It worked! sorry, i did repost the same updated question only because i didnt see your edit, and i been stuck for a few hours. I feel dumbfounded that i just needed a period. (as I was on the right track, I had standard = $selectedLanguge. Thanks Again!